# CSS Inheritance : conditionally remove background image

Tags: html, css

All images on my site are automatically given an icon next to them in css (see code example below).
For some links, I want to remove this icon.
For some links, I want to have a different icon.

So I though that css inheritance would do this but I cant seem to get it to work.

See Example.

```css
a { background: url('http://www.veryicon.com/icon/preview/System/Icons%20for%20Developers/smiley%20Icon.jpg') no-repeat center left; padding-left: 50px; }
a.icon { background: auto; padding-left: 0px;}
.frown { background : url('http://www.talkparanormal.com/images/smilies/misc4/frown.jpg')  no-repeat center left; padding-left: 50px; }
```

```html
<p><a href="#">test link</a></p>
<p><a href="#" tooltip="test icon" class="icon frown">test2</a></p>
<p><a href="#" tooltip="test icon" class="icon other">test2</a></p>
```

The first link is a normal site icon.

The second link should have an indent and a different image.
The third link should have no image and no indent..

Can anyone shed any light on what I can do to get this to work?  I am a bit wary of using `!important`, but I know that this will make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a.icon` has a higher specificity than `.frown`,

- `a.icon` specificity = 0,0,1,1  (11)
- `.frown` specificity = 0,0,1,0  (10)

...so its styles would take precedence.  Increasing the specificity of `.frown` should solve the problem:

```
/* 0,0,1,1 - equal but declared after so takes precedence */
a.frown { background : url('http://www.talkparanormal.com/images/smilies/misc4/frown.jpg')  no-repeat center left; padding-left: 50px; }

/* 0,0,2,0 - greater and not reliant on position in the CSS */
.icon.frown { background : url('http://www.talkparanormal.com/images/smilies/misc4/frown.jpg')  no-repeat center left; padding-left: 50px; }
```

See also:

- [Calculating a selector's specificity - w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.  I knew that it was something like this, but didnt know what to search for.  Thanks so much :)